# Как разместить обьекты в android studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

Почему все объекты  в android studio размещаются в левом верхнем углу?

Если на макете, я и могу выстроить:

[image]

то на смартфоне получаеться так:

[image]

Comment: RelativeLayout Вам в помощь

Comment: @iFr0z С этим так же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибуты из namespace `tools` учитываются **только** при предварительном просмотре `layout` (то есть при просмотре самого макета в IDE), непосредственно в приложении эти атрибуты не учитываются. Это т.н. *designtime layout attributes*.

> These are attributes which are used when the layout is rendered in the tool, but have no impact on the runtime. This is useful if you for example want to put sample data in your textfields for when you are editing the layout, but you don't want those attributes to affect your running app.

У Вас расположение `TextView` задается атрибутами:

```
tools:layout_editor_absolyteX
```

и

```
tools:layout_editor_absolyteY
```

которых в рантайме не будет, следовательно, элемент будет расположен по умолчанию (в левом верхнем углу).

**UPD**.

`TextView` по центру:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="123"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: но если я хочу задать ему другое местоположение , как мне это сделать?

Comment: @Jeck3ser, А Вам нужен именно `CoordinatorLayout`? Если нет, то смените его на другой контейнер и задавайте дочерним представлениям расположение согласно правилам расположения в выбранном контейнере.

Comment: я пытался и другим , но не получается текст расположить по центру , все время в левом верхнем углу
Смотрел видео на ютубе , таких проблем  у них нету

Comment: @Jeck3ser, Смотрите **UPD** в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в `tools:layout_edit_absoluteY` и `tools:layout_edit_absoluteY`. Вообще `tools` используется только что бы "показать в превью как оно будет выглядеть" но в "живую" эти параметры не учитываются. Поэтому результаты в макете и приложении отличаются.

Comment: даже если я и не буду смотреть на превью, то почему все эти объекты размещаются в левом верхнем углу?

Comment: @Jeck3ser, А какая разница: будете ли Вы смотреть или нет?